# Connect Access Database file (stored in Sharepoint) to Project file through VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, sharepoint-online, ms-project

My intention is to read an Access database file and use its data to create another Project file. Since now I was using a file stored in a local folder and my code was working properly. The code structure I've been using is the one below:

```
 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & File_PRJ_DB
        .Open
    End With
```

File_PRJ_DB was defined in another module:

`"C:\Users\Downloads...`

But now I need to do exactly the same but the database will be stored in Sharepoint. I've made research about this topic and was able to find some interesting options but none of them worked for me. I've tried converting the https path to WebDav format and using it as the ConnectionString but didn't work.
I'm pretty sure this is possible but I can't really find the solution to the issue.

All answers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really related to the SQL _language_. Consider a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Suggest you search SO for related posts such as [vba sharepoint adodb access](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]sharepoint+adodb+access). Also, consider editing your post to remove references to project since the core issue is connecting to an access database that resides in sharepoint.